# How to disable Format Document in VSCode, to excluding one line

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have this:

```
--addons=HorizontalPodAutoscaling,HttpLoadBalancing `
```

Format Document changes to this - adding a space between ","

```
--addons=HorizontalPodAutoscaling, HttpLoadBalancing `
```

Is there some `[AnalyserIgnoreTheFollowing line...]`?

Comment: what formatter do you use?

Comment: Don't know, I just installed: https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell

Comment: how do you format? on-save, or `ctrl + k` `ctrl + f`, ...?

Comment: It's done in your user settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode is highly customizable, and as with all products, it has defaults, but they can be altered using the WOrkspace and user settings.

> Visual Studio Code Tips and Tricks
>   https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks
>
> Visual Studio Code Formatting Setup
>   https://medium.com/@hamxiaoz/visual-studio-code-formatting-setup-9f40a95699ce
>
> User and Workspace Settings It is easy to configure VS Code to your
>   liking through settings. Nearly every part of VS Code's editor, user
>   interface, and functional behavior has options you can modify.
>
> VS Code provides two different scopes for settings:
>
> User These settings apply globally to any instance of VS Code you open
>   Workspace These settings are stored inside your workspace in a .vscode
>   folder and only apply when the workspace is opened. Settings defined
>   on this scope override the user scope.
>
> Creating User and Workspace Settings
>
> The menu command File > Preferences > Settings (Code > Preferences >
>   Settings on Mac) provides entry to configure user and workspace
>   settings. You are provided with a list of Default Settings. Copy any
>   setting that you want to change to the appropriate settings.json file.
>   The tabs on the right let you switch quickly between the user and
>   workspace settings files.
>
> https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getstarted/settings
>   https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings
>
> You can also configure language based settings by directly opening
>   settings.json. You can scope them to the workspace by placing them in
>   the workspace settings just like other settings. If you have settings
>   defined for a language in both user and workspace scopes, then they
>   are merged by giving precedence to the ones defined in the workspace.
>
> The following examples customize editor settings for language modes
>   typescript and markdown.

```
{
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true
  },
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off"
  }
}
```

> You can use IntelliSense in Settings editor to help you find allowed
>   language based settings. All editor settings and some non-editor
>   settings are supported

If you find you can't do it there, nothing prevents you from writing your own formatter.

> Creating a Formatter Extension
>   https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/11/15/formatters-best-practices